# What is the best way to join docs from two elasticsearch index?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

So I have two indices and their doc format/schema is like this

`index_1`

```
{
 "user_id": 1
 "user_group: "warriors"
}
```

`index_2`

```
{
 "user_group": "warriors"
 "group_point": 10
}
```

The ultimate goal is to get the doc like this

```
{
 "user_id": 1
 "user_group: "warriors"
 "group_point": 10
}
```

Just a few side notes

- The docs in `index_1` can change but extremely rare which means the group points are "mostly" same
- The docs in `index_2` can change but extremely rare which means the group points are "mostly" same
- I want the fastest way to get a doc possible as listed above

Now, I have a few ideas

- One is to just join them when retrieving but I would not like to make it slow while reading
- The other one is to always read the `group_point`, make a bulkier doc and then just write that doc to `index_1` which will basically contain everything. The problem however is in the rare occasion index2 docs change I have to update all the values in index1 docs as well

I was wondering if there are any better ways where I don't have to do heavy joins, can read docs fast, and easily update the group point without updating every possible doc in `index_1` ?

Comment: Unfortunately, using **Elasticsearch**; that's not applicable.

Comment: That as in what ? I listed a couple of ideas. Could you be more specific ? Thanks.

Comment: using **Elasticsearch**, you can't join docs from different indicies.